# Converging or Diverging function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem
given this series:

$ 1\over 5 $ + $ 2^2\over 5^2 $ + $3^2\over 5^3 $ + $4^2 \over 5^4 $

Does it converge or diverge and what test should be used. I have came to the conclusion that the limit approaches + infinity but don't know how to create a proof for that statement and whether it confirms that it diverges.
my apologies for the earlier version, that was my poor interpretation of the original problem, which I have updated this post with.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.   Also, you need to puth the MathJax commands inside `$` signs for the formatting to take effect.

Comment: Why would this sequence be bounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n=\dfrac{n^2}{5^n}$.  The sequence converges to $0$, since exponential growth is faster than polynomial.

As for the series, let's try the ratio test:  $\mid\dfrac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}\mid=\dfrac 15(\dfrac {n+1}n)^2\to\dfrac 15$.  Hence the series converges.

Comment: For any $k\gt0$, choose $N$ such that  $N\gt\sqrt {5k}$.  Then $n\gt N\implies a_n\gt k$.

Comment: I have updated to post to be more specific and easier to read

Comment: @JohnD.Rockefeller: Actually, you've updated the post to ask a radically different question, altogether. That said, for your sake, I'm glad you did.